# Empty consumer groups are not getting removed from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, ksqldb

In my application, I am running a `ksql` push query for reading data from topic. When push query is created, consumer group is created in `kafka`.

When I terminate push query, the consumer groups still present in `kafka` but in Empty state i.e. without any consumer present in it.

Does `kafka` automatically deletes such consumer groups ? In my setup I see its not getting deleted.

any explanation would be helpful.